# What are No Damage Test Scripts?

Tags: terminology, application-software-testing

I've done a few searches using different parameters but haven't come across a particular term being bandied about on a project team I've been working with.

Specifically, I'm hearing the phrase 'no damage test scripts' and despite asking a few people what exactly this means, apparently nobody seems to have a concise definition.

Have any of you encountered this term and if so what does it mean to you?

Comment: we really need more context to answer this, I would imagine that in some contexts "damage" could mean exactly that- physical or logical damage to something.

Comment: Fair point and I want to add for clarity that this is entirely related to software rather than any hardware or physical components.

Answer (score 1):

I think what they are talking about are test scripts that could be run in Production without any change to production data.

by this I mean that no data is entered into the system,

- nothing is created
- nothing is deleted
- nothing is ordered
- nothing is submitted
- etc.

smoke testing is a good example of what I think they mean by `No Damage`